# Sql Server print affected rows during while loop

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, printing

I have a stored procedure running on sql server 2008 looping over a table of ~50 million rows, deleting records one day at a time (approx. 25,000 records a day). I want to be able to watch this occur as the process runs via print statements to the messages window. I'd like to be able to see a message each time a day's worth of deletions is committed. Is there any way to do something like this? The procedure is roughly laid out like this:

```
WHILE EXISTS(<query statement>)
BEGIN

BEGIN TRAN

DELETE
FROM  <table>
WHERE <condition>
AND <condition>

--need some sort of "rows affected" statement here

COMMIT

END
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Unfortunately, PRINT statement output is spooled up and not written to the output immediately. A way round this is to use RAISERROR like this:

```
RAISERROR ('MY MESSAGE', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
```

Specifically for what you want:

```
    DECLARE @Msg VARCHAR(200)

    WHILE EXISTS(<query statement>)
    BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN

    DELETE
    FROM  <table>
    WHERE <condition>
    AND <condition>

    SELECT @Msg = CAST(@@ROWCOUNT AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' rows affected'
    RAISERROR (@Msg, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT

    COMMIT
    END
```

I also tend to include the current time in the message so I can record progress against time.

Comment: This works, but I'm still not quite sure how to grab the number of rows affected by the delete during each batch. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Make sure to look at the "Messages" tab in SSMS to see the output of RaiseError. The RaiseError output will only appear in the results tab AFTER the query is finished.

Comment: As Chris Smith noted, look at Messages tab (next to Results tab) or change your output mode to Text instead of Grid.

Answer (score 3):

Anything more complex than select @@rowcount ?

Comment: Nice and un-complex!

Answer (score 0):

How about using the OUTPUT clause?? Can you write to the SQL Server console from your stored proc??

Like in a trigger, you have a "Deleted" pseudo-table at your hands, which contains the rows that are being deleted, with all their columns.

```
WHILE EXISTS(<query statement>)
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRAN

  DELETE FROM  <table>
  OUTPUT deleted.ID, deleted.TimeStamp -- or whatever
  WHERE <condition>
  AND <condition>

  COMMIT

END
```

Comment: I don't necessarily want to see each row that was deleted per batch, but just the total count of them. I'm not sure you could get that functionality with the OUTPUT clause.

Comment: You could direct the OUTPUT into a temporary table and then count the rows in that temporary table after the WHILE loop.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do something similar to this, and because prints where spooled up it was not much use, however I discovered that the command line utility `osql` outputs them immediately, so I wrote the stored proc and called it from a batch file instead, which let me see the progress.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this to iterate over each row

```
           declare @ii (id int) table 

     -- for batchchunk operations      

          declare @numTransactions as int = 0,          
            @totalRowsInserted as int = 0,          
            @chunksize int = 0,          
            @printnow varchar(1000)      


      --does the initial insert into the  table       
            select * from #table       
            SET @numTransactions =@@rowcount       
            SET @printnow = 'Should Insert :'+cast(@numTransactions as varchar)+ ' rows into the  table.'          
            exec db.printNow @printnow;       -- shortened proc

           BEGIN           
           INSERTCHUNKS:          

           SET ROWCOUNT @Batchsize                 



          insert into table                   
          (                  
            type_id,                  
            parent_id,                  
            created_by_user_id,                  
            created_at,                  
            updated_by_user_id,                  
            updated_at,                  
            created_by_system_id,                  
            updated_by_system_id,                  
            is_deleted                   
           )                  
          output inserted.id into @ii(id)                  

           select                  
          1,--party_type_id                  
         NULL,--parent_party_id                  
         @user_id, --created_by_user_id                  
         case when created_at is NULL then getdate() else created_at end ,                               

         NULL , --updated_by_user_id                  
         case when updated_at is NULL then getdate() else updated_at end, --
         updated_at                  
         case when created_by_system_id is null then 292 else 0 end, --created_by_system_id                  
          updated_by_system_id,--updated_by_system_id                   \
           0 --is_deleted                  
         from                   
         #table         
         order by id asc            
         OFFSET            
         @TotalRowsInserted ROWS           
         FETCH NEXT @batchsize ROWS ONLY       
         set @chunksize =@@rowcount             
          IF @chunksize > 0      
          BEGIN             
         set @totalRowsInserted = @totalRowsInserted + @chunksize             
          SET @printnow = 'Batch done: ' +
            cast(@chunksize as varchar) + ' rows in Batch ; '          
            + cast(@totalRowsInserted as varchar) + ' total inserted so far 
             into the table.'             exec db.printnow @printnow;            

           waitfor delay '00:00:01'          
          GOTO INSERTCHUNKS           
          END        
          SET ROWCOUNT 0;      
          END
```

Answer (score -1):

Do the following:

```
DECLARE @queryCount AS INT, @start AS INT, @stop as INT, @table as varchar(max)

SELECT @start = cnt(*) as a FROM <table>

SELECT @queryCount = cnt(*)
    FROM  <table>
    WHERE <condition>
    AND <condition>

DELETE
    FROM  <table>
    WHERE <condition>
    AND <condition>

SELECT @stop = cnt(*) as a FROM <table>

PRINT(convert(varchar(max), @queryCount) + ' rows deleted from ' + convert(varchar(max), @table))
```

If you want to validate, you can throw in the following code.

```
PRINT('Rows at start: ' + convert(varchar(max), @start))
PRINT('Rows at end: ' + convert(varchar(max), @stop))
PRINT('Row difference: ' + convert(varchar(max), @start - @stop))
```

Caveat: If the database can affect rows while this is going on, you may see discrepancies.

Comment: The SQL server tends to buffer the print commands and outputs them all at the end of the loop. Can you please explain how is this going to work when is being used in a loop statement?